# What's the correct way to POST a compressed JSON string with RestSharp?

Tags: api, http, rest, restsharp

I want to use RestSharp to `POST` something somewhere.  I'm posting straight JSON (and not POCOs).  Because I'm posting plain JSON, I believe I need to use this workaround instead of setting `Body`:

```
request.AddParameter(
    "application/json", myJsonString, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

This works fine **when I'm not compressing the JSON**.  When I do, using this:

```
request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
request.AddParameter(
    "application/json", 
     GZipStream.CompressString(myJsonString), 
     ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

This doesn't work.  I stepped through the code and in `RestClient::ConfigureHttp`, I see:

```
http.RequestBody = body.Value.ToString();
```

Since I'm giving at a byte array, `body.Value` is set to `System.Byte[]`

Is there a way for RestSharp to handle a gzipped json string in a POST request?